# Train classifiers on a subset and validate on a full dataset

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, maximum-likelihood, dataset

Let's say I want to train a classifier and use it on 20% of "known" data; the rest of the "known" data is reserved for training (60%) and testing (20%). In the end I also want to apply it on "unknown" data and perform a maximum likelihood fit between "known" and "unknown" data in the distribution of the classifier output, so naturally I need to reserve as much "known" data for the validation as possible.

However, what if I instead:

- split the data in half -- say $A$ and $B$ -- by some universal and random feature present in both "known" and "unknown" data;
- use dataset $A$ to train a classifier $C_A$ and use it to classify $B$;
- use dataset $B$ to train another classifier $C_B$ and use it to classify $A$;
- combine both classifiers into a single classifier $C_{AB}$ to also classify "unknown" data.

In this scenario I could use 75% of "known" data for training, 25% for testing and 100% for classifying.

Is this a valid procedure? What kind of biases or restrictions am I potentially dealing with? Is the ratio between $A$ and $B$ important?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you assume that your data is random. Because of this when you train your model on a portion of the data set (training data) you in return get a model that can be tested on the test data set. So you get classifiers from the first portion and using some type of predictive model measurement you determine how well it did.

By going back and using any part of the test data set to create new classifiers to determine how well it explains the original training data set you are in turn "data drudging". This is because you are no longer testing the adequacy of the model but trying to over fit the model by estimating classifiers that only explain that data.

The data that you have is a sample (hopefully randomized) of a larger population with a goal of being able to predict some type of response. If you don't have a lot of data cut your data in half and use bootstrap techniques to estimate your model parameters. If cutting the data in half is too much you need more data.

In addition make sure that when you split your data you are doing it at random.